# MySQL, Best way to select entries with many one-to-many relationships?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Lets say I got a table *Products* and I got 3-4 other tables(Comments, Pictures, Orders and so on) connected to Products with  one-to-many relationship.

How should I  select one product and its connected entries from the other tables(Comments, Pictures, Orders) in a easy manner?

I tried using left joins connecting the other tables but i get duplicated entries. This will also get worse if i wanted to select many products instead of one.

I was also thinking of one query for each related table but isn't this too slow?

Comment: you shuld improve your question: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: what is exactly your desired output? (can u give an example?)

Comment: You do not get duplicated entries, you get one row for each possible join that meets the condition for the original row, this is what a ONE TO MANY is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have e.g.
1 Product
4 comments for said product
10 pictures and
5 orders
and if you do a left join you get 4*10*5=200 results with lots of duplicate comments, pictures and orders. But you only want one row per comment, picture and order.

You will need a separate query for each related table. If there was a way around that, it would be more complex and slower than the separate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting duplicate rows, you are getting the correct result of performing a one to many join.

Read up on:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Joins_and_join-like_operators
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

If you want one row per product entry consider using an aggregate function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

```
select product.id, product.name, group_concat(comment.text), avg(rating.value)
from product
left join comment on comment.product_id=product.id
left join rating on rating.product_id=product.id
group by product.id, product.name
```